# What value between 0 px and 227 px will make this dialog go away?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I have a picture contained within a drawing canvas in Word 2007. I made the mistake of right clicking and choosing format picture. This is the result:

[image]

Regardless of the values I enter into any of the boxes, this message appears:

> The measurement must be between 0 px and 227 px.

Even clicking cancel causes this to appear. As such, I am unable to close the format picture window, and save my document.

How can I get this stupid dialog to go away, without ending the process in task manager?

Comment: Is the measurement in question on a different tab?  Try using integer numbers (113 px), not fractions (113.5 px).

Comment: You also don't have a space between the value and "px".

Comment: @Hand-E-Food: It doesn't allow me to change tab either. I tried integer values as well, with and without spaces by the px, but that didn't help. Heck, I even tried putting a pixel value in the rotation field.